# Does wp track views for posts?

Tags: wp-query, sort, views

I want to do a query and sort posts by views. Is this possible? I'm not even sure where to start..

Comment: take a look at https://gist.github.com/2175805

Comment: @Bainternet In a high traffic scenario there will be a race condition with this approach.

Comment: @BrianFegter not really but it will lose count if a simple cache plugin is in place.

Comment: @Bainternet A race condition will occur if more than one connections are trying to increment that postmeta at the same time. I've built one of these before for a site with millions of hits a day and it's a reality. To route the caching, we did it asynchronously combined with memcache. We then converted memcache over to postmeta at intervals. If it's a low traffic scenario, there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @BrianFegter That makes sense :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress does not maintain post view count by default.

But you may find the following post helpful.

[Does wordpress have a post hit counter?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28862/does-wordpress-have-a-post-hit-counter)

You may also have a look on the [WP-PostViews](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/) plugin.

Many thanks.